# Drag & Drop Button not clickable, flickering Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have implemented a working drag and drop functionality to some buttons in my UI.
All the buttons have 'AllowDrop=true' enabled (so any button is a source/target).

All the buttons are now NOT clickable, and when the mouse is over a button the cursor flickers between the normal cursor and the dragging cursor. I implemented AllowDrop= false then true, and it flickers less but still flickers.

Code below

```
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            button.AllowDrop = false;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(button, button.Background.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
            button.AllowDrop = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I did not use parenthesis around the if statement:              if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))